# The Bootstrap Modal no longer opens

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

After a Wordpress update, I can no longer get the lines of code I wrote to open modals to work, clicking on the image opened a modal with text, spotify and youtube player and links to social networks inside. I am attaching the link to the site page: https://www.festadellamusicact.it/fdm19/
In the console I have the following error: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://open.scdn.co/cdn /build/embed/embed.fabac9a1.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net :: ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
This is the code:

```
    <div id="luchè" class="modal distanza">
        <div class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="https://www.festadellamusicact.it/wp-content/uploads/luchè.jpg" class="img-responsive img-modale">
            <h1 class="nomeartista">Luchè</h1>
            <h2 class="genere">[Hip Hop] -IT- </h2></br>
            <p class="descrizione">Luca Imprudente aka Luchè nato a Napoli il 7 Gennaio 1981 , inizia la sua carriera nel mondo dell'hip hop come rapper/producer del duo Napoletano CoSang.
```

Comment: take a look to your console browser you have a lot of errors

Comment: I only see two errors

Comment: you have a lot of cross site origin errors. on this remote resource https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different versions of Bootstrap JS being downloaded on your website.

Version 4.1.3 ->  https://www.festadellamusicact.it/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js?ver=1

Version 4.1.0 -> https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Remove one of them and it will work fine.